# Batch size to avoid overfitting

Tags: python, text-classification, overfitting-underfitting, batchsize

I have written code for binary text classification using XLM-RoBERTaForSequenceClassification. My train_dataset is made up over 8.000 data. For training I have used a batch size=32. The text hasn't been cleaned too much (I removed tickers, number, lowercase, hyperlinks, hashtags, words with 2 or fewer letters, words with 2 or fewer letters, words with 2 or fewer letters, emoticon) but I get overfitting after only 10 epochs. My question is, if I increase the batch size it is possible to "avoid" overfitting?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that particular model works but normally batch size does not affect the overfitting. Batch size affects how quickly the model converges with larger batch sizes leading to quicker convergence.

Comment: thats a question for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try to reduce the epoch size and reduce the data with same features, it may help you!

Comment: maybe to avoid overfitting you must enlarge the dataset (how many example did you have? How many MB or GB of data you have?), but if you start from pre-trained 10 epochs are not small number generally 3 or 4 is enough.

Comment: I use a pretrained: 'model = XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "xlm-roberta-base", 
    num_labels = 2,  
    output_attentions = False,  output_hidden_states = False)'
Hence, I can use less epochs?!

Comment: Yes for Bert models you can use lower number of epochs, as @NicolaLandro has mentioned. Besides are you retraining or just going to predict